# How to solve median without using vectors in C++?

Tags: c++

I wanted to code a program to find the mean and median of a sorted array (*so that I can do my maths homework faster*) without using vectors.
I wrote this program in HackerRank:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[2500],x;
    double sum, mean;
    cin>>x;

    //solving for mean
    for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    sort(arr, arr + x);
    sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (x-1); i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    mean = sum/x;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<mean<<endl;


    //solving for median
    if (x%2==0)
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<arr[x/2]<<endl;
    else 
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<((arr[(x-1)/2] + arr[x/2])/2.0)<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The input was:

```
10
64630 11735 14216 99233 14470 4978 73429 38120 51135 67060
```

And the expected output was:

```
43900.6
44627.5
```

But my output is:

```
43900.6
51135
```

I am unable to figure out the issue so please help

Comment: @RetiredNinja nope it still doesn't work :(

Comment: "without using vectors" is a weird condition. Why? Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: You ask for `x + 1` numbers as an input, but then apply `std::sort` to first `x` only. Why is that?

Comment: Seems like this program would invoke undefined behavior if the user enters 2500 or larger on the first line of stdin.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: a debugger can help you realize this quickly, you really need to learn how to use it if you want to learn programming [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/995714)

Comment: @evg Sorry, forgot I said anything, you are right to average the two for even numbered inputs.

Comment: The mean is the output expected, so only the median is wrong. Output the sorted array, output the calculated index/indices and the referred to value (by the index), then you see, which step had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x%2==0)
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<arr[x/2]<<endl;
else 
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<((arr[(x-1)/2] + arr[x/2])/2.0)<<endl;
```

if `x` is odd then `(x-1)/2` and `x/2` returns the same value, so `(arr[(x-1)/2] + arr[x/2])/2.0` is just equivalent to `arr[x/2]`. You need to use

```
(arr[x/2] + arr[(x + 1)/2])/2.0
```

or

```
(arr[x/2] + arr[x/2 + 1])/2.0
```

Comment: Still showing the same output @phuclv

Comment: no, it should work. `x/2` and `(x + 1)/2` must be different from each other

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

The odd/even check is reversed. If the number of items is even the middle two numbers are averaged and if it is odd the middle number is the median.

```
if (x%2==0)
```

should be
`if (x%2!=0)` or `if (x%2)`
You could also swap the contents of the `if` and `else`.

The calculation of the two middle indices is incorrect.

```
((arr[(x-1)/2] + arr[x/2])/2.0)
```

should be

```
((arr[x / 2 - 1] + arr[x / 2]) / 2.0)
```

With both of those issues corrected the output is the expected

```
43900.6
44627.5
```

[online example of corrected code](https://godbolt.org/z/hcs3orn1M)

Minor issues:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
```

If `x == 10` this will attempt to read 11 numbers. It should be `i < x`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (x-1); i++)
```

This is correct, but can be simplified to `i < x`.

Comment: `if (x%2!=0)` often is shortened to `if (x%2)`, which can be read quite naturally as `!= 0` as it appears so often.

Comment: @Sebastian Good point, that is how I would normally write it too but didn't want to lose the `==` to `!=` change so I showed both. If I was rewriting it completely I'd just have `double median = arr[x / 2]; if (x % 2 == 0) { median += arr[x / 2 - 1]; median /= 2.0; }` and avoid the `else` and duplication.

Answer (score -1):

Change your if condition. x is the length of the array from 0. So if length of array is 12, x will essentially be 11.

First of all, the input loop should be

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
    cin>>arr[i];
}
```

and the median should be like

```
if (x%2 == 1)
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<arr[x/2]<<endl;
else 
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<((arr[(x-1)/2] + arr[x/2])/2.0)<<endl;
```